# Trying to update only a rectangle in a widget in Qt, but the entire widget's area is updated instead

Tags: c++, qt

This happens in Qt Simulator (for phones). I'm trying to update only a portion of a widget's area, but the entire widget is updated instead.

To illustrate, the following code:

```
void Widget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    update(0, 0, 10, 10);
}

void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->rect();
}
```

Gives the following debug output when I click on the widget:

> QRect(0,0 458x832)

Which is the entire area of the widget.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Edit**

I ran the same code on Linux, and it worked as it should, the debug output was

> QRect(0,0 10x10)

Comment: Experiencing the same problem on iOS and MAC, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most GUI framework I've seen you can't update just some part of the application window/widget. Even if there's some function in API to update some rectangle - like update(x,y,x,y) you're using - it's just to inform the Framework that it needs to update **at least** the given rectangle, and framework can update a bigger part of the screen.

I'm not sure how it works in phone Qt but it's done this way in desktop version because in most OSes GUI application doesn't store its 'image' anywhere, and if you minimize and then show your window you need to recreate entire surface.

All this means that you can't rely on the assumption, that you'll paint something and then you'll be adding other paint operations in some custom rectangle when you need. You should implement some general 'paint' function, that can redraw everything from scratch and leave the painting optimization to the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Qt on the phones. But maybe something else is triggering the update of the whole widget. Qt sends one `paintEvent` for all `update()` called during one event loop processing. So your code may be calling for a partial update but somewhere in the window system may somehow get touched and calls for a full update.

Try [`repaint()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#repaint-7) and see if that sends your paintEvent the right region.

Comment: Good idea. I tried, it still invalidates the entire area, though. I should check if it has the same behavior on the actual phone though. Might be just a quirk of the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this bug was present only in Qt Simulator. On the actual phone itself, the update region was being passed correctly. I tested this by displaying a `QMessageBox` with the coordinates of `event->rect`.