# custom painting over QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qt5

I want to put some text with information about scene on `QGraphicsView`.

So I've inherited from `QGraphicsView` then I've overrided `paintEvent` and I do my drawings there.

It seemd fine however very quickly I've realized that my drawings are being updated only when there is an item moving near them. So what comes to my mind is that there is some clipping, however I cannot find where is it set and how can I obey it.

My painting routine:

```
void ObjectsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);

    const int fps = m_controller->fps();
    const QString info = QString(tr("Information about simulation: FPS: %1"))
                         .arg(fps);

    QPainter painter(viewport());
    const QRect infoRect = painter.boundingRect(QRect(), 0, info);

    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.drawText(infoRect.bottomLeft(), info);
    painter.drawLine(QPoint(), viewport()->rect().bottomRight());
}
```

Comment: Clipping is set by `update`. Here is a relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11707768/2988730. If you want to update your output, you need to add a call to `update` with whatever frequency you want it to be redrawn.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I see... I hoped there would be nicer solution.